# Jenkins plugin Kubernetes Credential Provider issue

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying to fix the error on the Manage Jenkins section -

Credentials from Kubernetes Secrets will not be available.See the log for more details.[image]

I see the following error below when I click on ***See the log for more details*** -

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Name or service not known
```

and Jenkins system logs says
[image]

Jenkins version: 2.368
Kubernetes Credentials Provider Plugin version: 1.206.v7ce2cf7b_0c8b

Any pointers to fix the same would be really great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error [**java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Name or service not known**](https://aws.plainenglish.io/jenkins-failed-to-initialize-kubernetes-secret-provider-fe87a240477) is caused by installing the Jenkins plug-in (Kubernetes Credentials Provider) and not using it. You need to close or uninstall the plug-in and this message will not appear. if you need to connect Kubernetes via Jenkins, install the [Kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/)

Credentials will be added and updated by adding/updating them as secrets to Kubernetes. The format of the Secret is different depending on the type of credential you wish to expose, but will all have several things in common. Find these [examples](https://jenkinsci.github.io/kubernetes-credentials-provider-plugin/examples/).